# How to display password policy information for a user?

Tags: password

[Ubuntu Documentation > Ubuntu 9.04 > Ubuntu Server Guide > Security > User Management](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/serverguide/C/user-management.html) states that there is a default minimum password length for Ubuntu:

> By default, Ubuntu requires a minimum
>   password length of 4 characters

Say the password is to be modified by the user using `passwd`. Is there a command for displaying the current password policies for a user (such as the `chage` command displays the password expiration information for a specific user)?

```
> sudo chage -l SomeUserName
Last password change                                : May 13, 2010
Password expires                                    : never
Password inactive                                   : never
Account expires                                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

This is rather than examining various places that control the policy and interpreting them since the process could contain errors. A command that reports the composed policy would be used to check the policy setting steps.

This question, [How to display password policy information for a user (Ubuntu)?](https://superuser.com/questions/150675), was posted on superuser but the request for it to be migrated to here was refused.

Comment: Note: this question has some good answers on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/150675/216900) already.